# Any success with asp.net and Less/Sass

Tags: asp.net, saas

I wanted to dive into learning some asp.net with C# and I wanted to know if anyone has had **success** with using Less or Sass?  All I can find search wise is little bits of info and some suggestions with a ton of issues.  I'd really like to find something **solid** on a successful site that has implemented Sass or Less, documentation, or a site that has a list of full issues and suggestions.

I have:

- Google searched "asp.net and Less
- Google searched "asp.net and Sass"
- "asp.net successful sites with Sass"
- "asp.net successful sites with Less"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some links you may find useful, I must mention that ASP.NET is by far **NOT** my strongest skill. You are more than likely to get a **better answer from someone else** but from what I've read I believe that most people use [Dot Less CSS](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) and use [NuGet](http://nuget.codeplex.com/) to add the package.

I've included many other links since your Goggle search wasn't the best for narrowing down results. Again I'll imagine you get a better answer than this but in the mean time while you wait here is some links to keep your mind busy ;)

**Less Vs Sass**

- [Less Vs Sass](http://css-tricks.com/sass-vs-less/)
- [Introduction to less and comparison to sass](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/09/09/an-introduction-to-less-and-comparison-to-sass/)
- [Sass vs Less vs Stylus A Preprocessor Shootout](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/sass-vs-less-vs-stylus-a-preprocessor-shootout/)

**Less Links for ASP.NET**

- [Dot Less CSS](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) - [***Documentation Wiki Here***](http://github.com/dotless/dotless/wiki)
- [Less with .NET MVC Part 1 installing Less](http://preprogrammed.wordpress.com/2011/12/02/less-with-net-mvc-part-1-installing-less/)
- [Less CSS the .net Edition](http://blog.smoothfriction.nl/archive/2010/01/09/lesscss-the-.net-edition.aspx)
- [Bootstrap with LESS for ASP.NET](http://www.annhoang.net/twitter-bootstrap-in-visual-studio-2010-with-chirpy-and-dotless/)
- [Combining Less with ASP.NET](http://www.sitepoint.com/combining-less-with-asp-net/)

**Sass Links for ASP.NET**

- [Lib Sass Net](http://libsassnet.codeplex.com/)
- [Getting Started with SASS for Microsoft Developers](http://dontcodetired.com/blog/post/Getting-Started-with-SASS-for-Microsoft-Developers.aspx)
- [Stack Overflow - Sass and ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13056611/sass-and-asp-net)
- [Use less sass and compress with ASP.NET MVC](http://tostring.it/2012/09/27/use-less-sass-and-compass-with-asp-net-mvc/)
- [Sass with ASP.NET MVC4 Twitter Bootstrap](http://tsubik.com/blog/sass-with-aspnet-mvc4-twitter-bootstrap-example/)
- [Deep Dive into ASP.NET Sass and More](http://blog.mirajavora.com/deep-dive-into-asp.net-bundling-and-minification)
- [Using Sass with ASP.NET another Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/796788/using-sass-with-asp-net)